# Ortho imagery out of position in Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm creating various plots in QGIS using layouts.

For some reason my ortho imagery, whether it be sourced from GeoTiff or WMS, is shifting independent of my linework in the layouts. Everything looks fine in the main QGIS view, everything is locked in place and correctly georeferenced. All layers are on the Project CRS along with the map view in the layout.

Interestingly when I move or scale the plan within the map layout item the imagery moves to different places independent of the linework. As if the images are draped on a globe a long way below my linework.

Is this a bug or have I gotten something wrong here?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.